# Excel VBA - Get copied cell address when the active/selected cell is different

Tags: excel, vba

When using VBA in Excel, is there any way to get the address of a copied cell when the active/selected cell is different?  The cell would be copied *before* running the macro.

For example, let's say cell R1 is currently copied, but the selected cell and the view (what I'm seeing on screen) is over somewhere in column ZAA.  As a simple example, I want to essentially zoom back to the area with the copied cell without having to scroll over manually looking for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I just want to say that all of the solutions for this are quite hacky.

I think the best "hacky" method that works probably has a ton of edge cases, but I would just grab `CTRL+C` and `CTRL+X` (cut and copy shortcuts) and do things with them.

This won't work with the context menu cut and copy methods - there are ways to try to get those, but they are buggy (mainly bugs if you copy one thing and then copy another thing without resetting the `CutCopyMode`) I'm not sure if there is a way to detect a "new" cut/copy when an old one is currently active (you certainly can't do this by checking `Application.CutCopyMode`).

One other (potentially?) nice thing about this method is that it actually follows the range you cut when you paste it ... so if you jump again, you will see where it was moved to (note that if cutting and pasting to new sheet, this doesn't work).

In the Workbook Object:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Application.OnKey "^c", "CopyFired"
Application.OnKey "^x", "CutFired"
End Sub
```

In a module:

```
Dim CutCopyRange As Range
Sub CopyFired()
Set CutCopyRange = Selection
Selection.Copy
End Sub

Sub CutFired()
Set CutCopyRange = Selection
Selection.Cut
End Sub

Sub JumpToRange()
'You can add CutCopyRange.Parent.Select if you switch worksheets
'But this will not follow a cut->paste from one sheet to another properly
'The Range seems to update itself, but not its parent.
If Not CutCopyRange Is Nothing Then CutCopyRange.Select
End Sub
```

You may also want to setup `Worksheet_Change` captures to clear the `CutCopyRange` if `Application.CutCopyMode` is false, but I wouldn't mess with all that. Provided they use `CTRL+C` to copy and `CTRL+X` to cut, you should be able to capture it by simply capturing the presses.

Note that this code likely also has bugs if you try to cut/copy objects on a worksheet.

Call `JumpToRange` to jump to the current range - if it's on a different sheet, you likely need to select the sheet first - there may be some additional code associated with this.

I think you can also use `ScrollTo` instead of `Select`, but that's dealer's choice I suppose.

[image: Demo]

Comment: Awesome; it works perfectly!  It should always be the basic CTRL+x/c so it should be fine.

Thanks a lot for the help!  I had no idea these kinds of things were possible so I have a few things I can go research now.

Comment: No problem! :) Happy to help

Answer (score 0):

This is a simplified version of code I've been using to do this for quite a few years, and I think it works reliably. It returns the copied range (if there is one) no matter whether the copying was done via `Ctrl+C` or `Ctrl+Insert` or via the right-click context menu or the ribbon.

```
Public Function GetCopiedRange()
    Dim Cell1 As Range
    Dim Cell2 As Range
    Dim ConvexHull As Range
    Dim CopyOfErr As String
    Dim Format As Variant
    Dim Formats As Variant
    Dim Formula1 As String
    Dim Formula2 As String
    Dim SU As Boolean
    Dim tempBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim TempRange As Range

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    If Application.CutCopyMode <> xlCopy Then
        Err.Raise vbObjectError + 1, , "#No copied Range found!"
        Exit Function
    End If
    'Examine ClipBoard formats to check that what's copied is indeed a range
    'Found this tip at http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=66773
    Formats = Application.ClipboardFormats
    For Each Format In Formats
        If Format = xlClipboardFormatCSV Then
            GoTo Continue
        End If
    Next
    Err.Raise vbObjectError + 1, , "#No copied Range found!"
    Exit Function
Continue:
    SU = Application.ScreenUpdating
    If SU Then Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set tempBook = Application.Workbooks.Add
    tempBook.Worksheets(1).Paste Link:=True
    Set TempRange = Selection

    With TempRange
        Formula1 = .Cells(1, 1).Formula
        Formula2 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Formula
    End With

    'Rubberduck (2.4.1.4627) incorrectly flags these three lines as implicitly referencing the active sheet
    Set Cell1 = Range(Right$(Formula1, Len(Formula1) - 1))
    Set Cell2 = Range(Right$(Formula2, Len(Formula2) - 1))
    Set ConvexHull = Range(Cell1, Cell2)
    'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull

    If ConvexHull.Cells.CountLarge = TempRange.Cells.CountLarge Then
        ' Copied Range had one area only.
        Set GetCopiedRange = ConvexHull
    Else
        'There are now two possibilities:
        'a) Copied range had multiple areas, each of the same width and all aligned vertically; or
        'b) Copied range had multiple areas, each of the same height and all aligned horizontally.
        ' It is not possible to copy other layouts of multiple-area ranges (as of Office 2013)
        ' Coping with cases a) and b) is possible but complex, so just raise an error.
        Err.Raise vbObjectError + 1, , "Copied Range has multiple areas"
    End If
    tempBook.Close False
    If SU Then Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Exit Function
ErrHandler:
    CopyOfErr = Err.Description
    If Not tempBook Is Nothing Then tempBook.Close False
    If SU Then Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Err.Raise vbObjectError + 1, , CopyOfErr
End Function
```